# MongoDB cursor to hash in Perl

Tags: mongodb, perl, perl5.8, database

So, I'm retrieving some values from MongoDB. I now that `find` method returns a `cursor`, which lazy loads the query results. I want to have the cursor stored as a hash, but I can find any method. Of course, you can iterate over the cursor and fill the has by yourself, but I'm interested in a automated way. For example, in Python, you could do this: `myList = list(col.find())` to get all the cursor items as a list.

Would it be possible doing something similar in Perl?

Comment: What do you want the keys to be? The Python example you gave looks like an array. There is a method to get all of the documents at once.

Comment: @simbabque as mongo docs (http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Collection.pm) state, a document retrieved is the same as a hash. So I want to use as keys the keys from the retrieved document. Whihc mehtod are you talking about? it can be useful too

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::QueryResult#all gives all docs of the search at once as a list. I've never used MongoDB before, but it sounds to me that the `next` returns a full document. That's your hash.

Comment: @simbabque Sure! I was missunderstanting something when I read that, after asking here. Thank you for clarify, that solves my problem!!

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, just try and look at the data that comes back with Data::Dumper or similar. Docs can be confusing, but the data is what it is. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If you want to write the answer, I will gladly accept it @simbabque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `find`, it returns a [cursor object](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Cursor), which delegates iterator methods to a [MongoDB::QueryResult](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::QueryResult). When you do a `next` on that thing, it returns one document at a time lazily. That document already is the full set of data. This might be a hash reference already (or an object, I don't know).

```
use Data::Dumper;
while (my $object = $cursor->next) {
    print Dumper $object;
}
```

If you want all of them at once, you can get a list with the `all` method, which you can then put into an array and use at your convenience. This will not load on demand.

```
my @objects = $cursor->all;
```